# SSA Forecast with ML.NET returns strange results

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I've just started with ML.NET so I tried to adapt the tutorial from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/time-series-demand-forecasting) on my code, which should predict bookings in the future:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
    ModelInput[] modelInputFirstYear = Database.Instance.GetBookingsOfYear(2018).ToArray();
    ModelInput[] modelInputSecondYear = Database.Instance.GetBookingsOfYear(2019).ToArray();
    modelInputFirstYear = FillDates(modelInputFirstYear); //FillDates fills the array on days where no bookings were made with a date and the TotalBookings = 0, so it has 365 items
    modelInputSecondYear = FillDates(modelInputSecondYear);
    IDataView firstYear = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<ModelInput>(modelInputFirstYear);
    IDataView secondYear = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<ModelInput>(modelInputSecondYear);

    var forecastingPipeline = mlContext.Forecasting.ForecastBySsa(
        outputColumnName: "ForecastedBookings",
        inputColumnName: "TotalBookings",
        windowSize: 7, 
        seriesLength: 30,
        trainSize: 365, 
        horizon: 7,
        confidenceLevel: 0.95f,
        confidenceLowerBoundColumn: "LowerBoundBookings",
        confidenceUpperBoundColumn: "UpperBoundBookings");

    SsaForecastingTransformer forecaster = forecastingPipeline.Fit(firstYear);
    Evaluate(secondYear, forecaster, mlContext);
    var forecastEngine = forecaster.CreateTimeSeriesEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(mlContext);
    Forecast(secondYear, 7, forecastEngine, mlContext);
}

private static void Evaluate(IDataView testData, ITransformer model, MLContext mlContext)
{
    IDataView predictions = model.Transform(testData);
    IEnumerable<float> actual = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<ModelInput>(testData, true).Select(observed => observed.TotalBookings);
    IEnumerable<float> forecast = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<ModelOutput>(predictions, true).Select(prediction => prediction.ForecastedBookings[0]);
    var metrics = actual.Zip(forecast, (actualValue, forecastValue) => actualValue - forecastValue);
    var MAE = metrics.Average(error => Math.Abs(error));
    var RMSE = Math.Sqrt(metrics.Average(error => Math.Pow(error, 2))); 
    Console.WriteLine(" > Evaluation Metrics");
    Console.WriteLine($"     > Mean Absolute Error: {MAE:F3}");
    Console.WriteLine($"     > Root Mean Squared Error: {RMSE:F3}\n");
}

private static void Forecast(IDataView testData, int horizon, TimeSeriesPredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput> forecaster, MLContext mlContext)
{
    ModelOutput forecast = forecaster.Predict();
    IEnumerable<string> forecastOutput = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<ModelInput>(testData, reuseRowObject: false)
    .Take(horizon)
    .Select((ModelInput rental, int index) =>
    {
        string rentalDate = rental.BookingDate.ToShortDateString();
        float actualRentals = rental.TotalBookings;
        float lowerEstimate = Math.Max(0, forecast.LowerBoundBookings[index]);
        float estimate = forecast.ForecastedBookings[index];
        float upperEstimate = forecast.UpperBoundBookings[index];
        return $"Date: {rentalDate}\n" +
        $"Actual Rentals: {actualRentals}\n" +
        $"Lower Estimate: {lowerEstimate}\n" +
        $"Forecast: {estimate}\n" +
        $"Upper Estimate: {upperEstimate}\n";
    });
    Console.WriteLine(" > Rental Forecast");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    foreach (var prediction in forecastOutput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prediction);
    }
}
```

`ModelInput` and `ModelOutput` Classes:

```
public class ModelInput 
{
    public DateTime BookingDate { get; set; }
    public float Year { get; set; }
    public float TotalBookings { get; set; }
}

public class ModelOutput
{
    public float[] ForecastedBookings { get; set; }
    public float[] LowerBoundBookings { get; set; }
    public float[] UpperBoundBookings { get; set; }
}
```

But the forecast values return strange results:

[image: Output of the Application]

Comment: Looks like the negative zero is due to confidence .95 level at lower bound is outside the window.

Comment: @jdweng Okay, have you got any idea how to correct this?

Comment: I would plot the data and see what it looks like.  I believe .95 is 3 sigma.  So the .95 percent is either .707 of peak or .5 of peak (can't remember).  So the plot lower bound should fall inside the .707 or .5 point.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. We've had some problems with internationalization, and I notice you seem to be using commas to represent decimal points. Can you try using US formatted data and see if this fixes your problem?
2. A negative value may not be inaccurate. I notice you are taking the maximum of the lower bound and 0 in your code, but I bet if you returned the actual lower bound it would also be negative. It is possible your data actually suggest a negative trend.